# Can the effect of Object.freeze be reversed in ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Once I do this:

```
var x = { };
Object.freeze( x );
```

Is there any way to modify x?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nothing can be added to or removed from the properties set of a frozen
>   object. Any attempt to do so will fail, either silently or by throwing
>   a TypeError exception (most commonly, but not exclusively, when in
>   strict mode).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

You can think about it like this:

```
if( typeof ChuckNorris === 'undefined' ) {
    ChuckNorris = Object.create( [Infinity], {
        canCountTo: {
            value: Infinity * 2,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });

    Object.freeze( ChuckNorris ); // nothing can harm Chuck anymore !
}

console.log( ChuckNorris.canCountTo );  // Infinity
delete ChuckNorris.canCountTo;
console.log( ChuckNorris.canCountTo );  // Infinity
```

So basically, `freeze` will set the objects `writable` and `configurable` flags to false after creation.

Comment: And there is now way you can set those flags back to true?

Comment: Don't get me wrong I like it this way :P, but with JavaScript you can never be sure... I do not want to rely on this feature if the object can ever be made mutable again.

Comment: Unless there is some hackery I'm not aware of (unlikely :p), no there is no way to modify an freezed objects property when the JS engine supports it natively.

Answer (score 1):

No, the idea of `Object.freeze` is that you cannot change it anymore. According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

> In essence the object is made effectively immutable.

and:

> Nothing can be added to or removed from the properties set of a frozen object. Any attempt to do so will fail, ...

Comment: So basically I can use this to make things "private"?

Comment: @Mike Shinola: It depends on how you define "private". Its values cannot be altered, but still read.